# Eclipse 3.7.2 or juno releases does not having org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseLog.java class in osgi package

Tags: java, eclipse

We are upgrading the Eclipse from 3.2.2 to 3.7.2(Indigo). 
As EclipseLog java file was present in osgi package of eclispe 3.2.2 and now looks like it is completely removed from later version of eclipse(3.7.2 or juno releases). Is there any alternative for EclipseLog class in 3.7.2 eclispe.

Answer (score 0):

The framework logging was changed to support OSGi services and Eclipse adapter hooks some time ago. You access the framework log using the service interface:

```
ServiceTracker logTracker = new ServiceTracker(context, FrameworkLog.class.getName(), null);
logTracker.open();

FrameworkLog log = (FrameworkLog)logTracker.getService();
```

`context` is the `BundleContext` passed to your plugin activator.

`FrameworkLog` has a `setWriter` method which allows you to change the writer used for the log.

If you want to override the `FrameworkLog` that is created you will need to configure the Eclipse adapter hooks - see [Adapter Hooks](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Adaptor_Hooks)

Comment: Thanks greg for your reply. We are try to implement Eclipselog class which implements frameworklog interface. We want to write few method such as  log(FrameworkEvent), log(FrameworkLogEntry), writeLog(int depth, FrameworkLogEntry entry), writeStack(FrameworkLogEntry entry) ,isLoggable(FrameworkLogEntry entry) ,setFile(file,boolean).

Comment: ...that is part of frameworklog class. As frameworklogging is changed and eclipselog is missing, is there any class where we can find the similar methods.

Comment: Added details of setWriter and Adapter Hooks reference